# How to connect to IBM Cloud Object Storage from R?

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have some data stored on IBM Cloud Object Storage and I want to access the data from my local R. It is pretty easy to do on Watson Studio with insert-to-code feature, but the same piece of code doesn't work on my local R:

```
> data_1 <- spark_read_csv(sc,'cleaned_1',save_paths[1], infer_schema = F, memory = F)
Error: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: cos
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:705)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:388)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:594)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:473)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:137)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anyone know how to access COS data from local machine?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use [the `aws.s3` library](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) from [the `cloudyr` project](https://github.com/cloudyr).

```
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "<access-key>",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "<secret-key>",
           "AWS_S3_ENDPOINT" = "https://s3.us-south.objectstorage.softlayer.net")

library(aws.s3)

s3load("mtcars.Rdata", bucket = "my_bucket")
```

You'll need to create the Access/Secret keys [(HMAC keys)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/service-credentials.html#service-credentials).

Comment: Thank you Nick that works! What if I have a pseudo-spark on local R and want to import data from COS as a spark data frame?